# How to print the binary value of negative numbers?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have been trying to find the binary representation of negative numbers. As per my knowledge the negative numbers are stored as a 2's complement in the computer. And, the MSB is 1, indicating that it is negative.

So, I have the following code to print the binary representation of any number::

```
void printBits(int n) {
    if((n >> 1) == 0) {
        cout << (n & 1);
        return;
    }
    printBits(n >> 1);
    cout << (n & 1);
}
```

But, it fails for negative numbers, probably because on left shifting the sign bit doesn't get changed, but does get shifted.
So, how do i print the binary representation.

There's a function `bitset`, which prints the representation like this:

`bitset<numberOfBitsRequired>(numberToBeRepresented)`

**I tried using it on ideone, which is probably a 64-bit compiler.
So, if in the `numberOfBitsRequired`, I give the input as `64`, I get this output::**

`1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

**But, if I change the `numberOfBitsRequired` to 65, I get::**

`01111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

**From the zero in the starting I can understand the the number of bits have been exceeded. Is there a way that I can find the config of the compiler?? Which I can later use to in my code for finding the bit representation.**

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: If you want to get the real representation used by the computer, I would suggest casting the pointer to `usigned int`. If you want to get some fixed representation not depending on the computer, you should choose the representation and then write a code for it.

Comment: Probably want to use a C++ idiom like std::bitset.

Comment: @Robinson yea, but how does bitset know the configuration of my compiler? Please see d part of the question I just highlighted!